# Ocx control in win form

Tags: c#-3.0, activex

How to create instance of AxHost abstract class

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot create an instance of an abstract class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(VS.71).aspx)

*You typically do not use the AxHost class directly. You can use the Windows Forms ActiveX Control Importer (Aximp.exe) to generate the wrappers that extend AxHost.*

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.axhost.aspx for an example.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamically adding ActiveX controls in managed code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AxForms.aspx) -- related, perhaps, along with [How to Create instance of a class defined in .Net Class Library without setting reference](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=56748)